# Как сформировать ссылку определённого вида?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Есть контроллер:

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #@news = News.all.order(created_at: :desc)
    @news = News.page(params[:page])
  end

  def show

  end  
end
```

Я пытаюсь сформировать ссылку типа:

```
<%= link_to 'More', controller: "news", action: "show", id: news_item.id %>
```

но многострочную. Для этого создаю следующий шаблон:

```
<% @news.each do |news_item| %>
    <%= link_to(news_path, { controller: "news", action: "show", id: news_item.id }) do %>
        <span>qwerty</span>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

В результате получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке:

```
NameError in News#index
Showing /home/kalinin/rails/visit/app/views/news/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined local variable or method `news_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f221c8a0738>:0x007f221c391dc8>
```

Comment: rake routes - просмотр имеющихся путей http://rusrails.ru/rails-routing#osmotr-i-testirovanie-marshrutov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"undefined local variable or method 'news_path'" -- У вас 'news_path' не существует. Думаю, имеется в виду путь к новостям, значит, вам стоит проверить ваши маршруты. Копайте routes.rb и команду 'rake routes'.

ЗЫ: Ссылку можно короче написать:  `link_to('text', news_path(news_item))`

ЗЗЫ: Учтите, что английское слово news не имеет множественной формы (точнее наоборот), значит ссылка на индексную страницу будет: `news_index_path()`

Comment: news_path существует, потому что такая ссылка работает:

    <%= link_to 'More', controller: "news", action: "show", id: news_item.id %>

Короче, ссылку записывать мне не нужно, мне нужно в неё заключить блок кода (большой).

Comment: news_path не существует. Об этом вам интерпретатор и говорит! Возьмите словарик и переведите: "undefined local variable or method 'news_path'"

news_path(), если мы говорим о помощнике из маршрутизатора, это обёртка для вызова url_for({controller: "news", action: "show", id: news_item.id}), поскольку вы передаёте хеш, то news_path в вашем варианте не используется.

Comment: вы правы. большое спасибо